# one particular command in bash script doesn't work when run by cron, all other commands do

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I have a bash script that runs a few commands including rsync and this one below

```
rm -f $(ls -1t /nas/backups | tail -n +161)
```

If I execute the script myself on the cli, all commands work. However if run by cron all commands work except the one above.

No idea why. The files in /nas/backups are owned by root, but cron is running as root.

Any ideas? thanks

Comment: You can verify if your script is really running as root by doing `echo "$USER" >> /some/file`. Try `echo "$(ls -1t /nas/backups | tail -n +161)" >> /some/file` as well. Check the file after running.

Comment: As a side note, `rm -f $(ls -1t /nas/backups ...` is rather insecure if some file names have (or might have -- in an undetermined future) spaces in them. Worst, what would append if there was (by an unexpected and rather unfortunate twist of fate) a file named `whatever -r` in your directory ?

Comment: To add to the above, something like `( IFS=$'\n'; for file in $(ls -t /nas/backups | tail -n +161); do rm -f -- "$file"; done )` would be far preferable, despite still breaking on files containing EOL. Though not at all clear if that's the issue, try adding some `-v` verbosity and redirecting cron output (including stderr) somewhere.

Comment: I appreciate the comments re security. This is just messing around at present and not a production server. Nice suggestions though @konsolebox I'm outputting $user to /tmp/cronuser and the file is blank. So it appears I was incorrect to assume that cron was running as root just because it was in root's crontab

Comment: @joevallender The variable is case-sensitive. It should be `$USER` (all-caps). `$user` would probably evaluate to nothing. Also consider `$HOME`.

Comment: Sorry, lazy typing. I used $USER in the script

Comment: Could you edit your question to show the corresponding line of your _crontab_? Is it configured in `/etc/crontab` or in some user-specific contab?

Comment: An other wild idea, could you launch `ps -f` (and log output) from your contab. We could see for sure under which identity it is running.

Comment: You said "bash script", but does it starts with `#!/bin/bash` or nothing or another ?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay in responding. I do have `#!/bin/bash` in the file. And the line `0 * * * * /usr/local/sbin/rsync_test` was added from `crontab -e` while logged in as root.

Comment: The script that creates the files that are owned by root and seemingly enable to be deleted by the next script is also in the same crontab

Comment: Just realised that the evaluated `ls` contains just filenames, not the path. So rm won't work unless working directory is changed to the backups folder. I've got a strong feeling this is the issue. Have changed and will check it's fixed then will look at the security issues if it works. Feel like a bit of a dummy here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. So I'm a dummy.

My `ls` command returns a list of file names, not file paths! And cron wasn't running in the correct working directory.